# Выбор WYSIWYG-редактора

Tags: wysiwyg

Здравствуйте.

Помогите подобрать WYSIWYG-редактор. Нужны инструменты для базового форматирования текста и вставка картинок.  Было бы круто, если бы был встроенный загрузчик изображений.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TinyMCE. Есть бесплатные плагины для загрузки картинок.

Answer (score 4):

Сам всегда интегрировал TinyMCE, пока не узнал про [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). К нему одним взмахом руки прикручивается [KCFinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/). Рекомендую.

Comment: не знал про KCFinder спасибо.